# Prove That Subset of Real Numbers is Countable

Tags: real-analysis

Let S be a subset of the positive real numbers such that the sum of any n numbers in S is less than or equal to N
$$x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_n \leq N$$

Prove that S is a countable set.

This is not a homework problem and I am not sure how to even start. I just wanted to know the answer out of intellectual curiosity.

Thanks you very much.

EDIT:

What if I consider S as the union of all sets of size n whose elements are less than or equal to N and belong to the positive real numbers.

Then I could arrange each such set as a row in tabular form:

[image]

And arrange them in such a sequence.

Could that work in proving S is countable?

Comment: Is $N$ fixed? Is $n$ not fixed? If the answer is "yes" to both, you could use the fact that if $S$ were uncountable, there would be an $\epsilon>0$ such that infinitely many members of $S$ exceed $\epsilon$.

Comment: Both N and n are fixed, yes.

Comment: If both are fixed, it's not true: $S=[0,1]$, $n=1$, $N=2$.

Comment: Are you sure that you are supposed to prove that $S$ is countable ?
As @DavidMitra said if n is fixed the set is uncountable and I am pretty sure this is also the case when n is not.

Comment: Can you post an answer proving it is uncountable?

Comment: What if I let S be the union of all sets of size n whose sum is less than or equal to N, wrote all of the n numbers for each set as rows in tabular form, drew arrows across diagonals? Will that work in proving it's countable?

Comment: Easier to argue first that, if $S$ is an uncountable set of positive numbers. then there is a number $c>0$ so that there are infinitely many elements $s∈S$ for which $s>c$.  Hint: Consider the sets $S_1$, $S_2$, $S_3$, ... where $$S_n= \left\{s\in S: s>\frac1n \right\}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Take $S=(0; \frac Nn)$ to refute the statement.